# How to compute P values for increasing sample size using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, random

I am having trouble creating a for loop. 
I want to increase my sample size from 1 to 200 and calculate a p value after each newly added observation.
So that first I sample 1 observation - calculate first p value, then sample 2 observations - calculate second p value, then 3... up to 200 observations so that I get 200 p-values.
The observations will all be sampled from one column of a data frame (with replacing).

Lets say the column of the data frame is called data$column1. 
The sample size increases by one in each "round" from 1:200.

How do I create a for loop so that for each "round", one more observation is being sampled and a new p value is being computed?
Finally I want to plot all p values.

```
n <- 1:200

for i in length(n) {
sample(data$column1,n, replace = TRUE)
pvalue <- t.test(data$column1, alternative = "greater")
}
```

Comment: (1) it is `for (i in 2:length(n))` or even better `for (i in seq_len(n)[-1])`, not `for i in ...`. (2) Try `pvalues <- sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) t.test(sample(data$column1,size=i), alternative="greater")$p.value)`. (I start at 2 because a t-test needs at least two data.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I just tried the code and its not working yet. This is my first time ever using a loop so I really appreciate your help!                   The data$column1 looks like this: (5,6,8,2,5,6,8,9,5,7,9,3,6,7,9,0,6,5,7,8,0,20), just numbers in each row of the column 
`n <- 1:200

for(i in seq_len(n)[-1]){
  sample(data$column1, n, replace = TRUE)
  pvalue <- sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) t.test(sample(data$column1,size=i), alternative="greater")$p.value)
  }`

Comment: The R Warning message is:
In seq_len(n) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

Comment: Oops, sorry. (1) That's a warning, not an error. (2) Use `for (i in seq_len(nrow(data))[-1])` or `for (i in n)`. (I skipped over your definition of `n`, my bad.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I recognize you may want to use `for` loops, this is a good opportunity to use `sapply` or `lapply`. I'll demonstrate alternatives using `iris`. Though I'm going to use the simplified test of "not equal to 5" for `iris$Sepal.Length` for all samples, you should update `alternative=` and other arguments for your specific data.

Choice 1: if all you ever need is the p-value, we can capture just that ... or we can capture the whole model and do a second-stage retrieval of the p-values.

Choice 2: we can use one of the `*apply` functions, which reads well (once you get more accustomed to R vector code), or you can stick with the `for` loop. There are readability benefits of the first option, though you might be more comfortable with a `for` loop, in which case you should really pre-allocate the list/vector. (Reason for pre-defining a long but empty list/vector: while you can easily concatenate a vector `out` with `out <- c(out, newstuff)`, doing this repeatedly is *very inefficient* in the long run. I highly discourage doing this in "large-ish scale".)

Up front, some notes:

- I use `set.seed(2)` for each one so that the results are identical. You should not use it until/unless you need strict reproducibility. Typically not desired for production/academic reports.
- I do `seq_len` instead of `2:length(...)` because of habit patterns: when doing things programmatically, it's good to have it fail gracefully. If for some reason in your future you use `1:length(nrow(x))` and `x` turns out to have 0 rows, then `1:0` produces a vector of length 2, which is counter-intuitive (and will almost certainly break follow-on code). Instead, `seq_len(0)` produces a vector of length 2, which is a good thing. Again, less critical here, but a good habit to get into. (BTW: `seq_along(0)` still outputs a vector of length 1, so it is prone to this problem, too.)
- I used `seq_len(...)[-1]` to discard the "1", because a t-test with a single datum cannot be done. One could also have done `1 + seq_len(nrow(x)-1)`.

### 1: `for` loop, p-value only

```r
set.seed(2)
out <- rep(NA, nrow(iris))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(iris))[-1]) {
  thisdat <- sample(iris$Sepal.Length, size = i)
  out[i] <- t.test(thisdat, mu = 5)$p.value
}
summary(out)
#      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
# 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0080013 0.0000001 0.4156151         1
```

(You can assume that `out` is identical for all follow-on examples, so I won't show it.)

### 2. `*apply`, p-value only

```r
set.seed(2)
out <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(iris))[-1], function(i) {
  thisdat <- sample(iris$Sepal.Length, size = i)
  t.test(thisdat, mu = 5)$p.value
})
```

`sapply` takes a vector and typically returns one of:

- `vector` if all return values are perfectly length 1;
- `matrix` if all return values are vectors of exactly the same length; or
- `list` any other time.

Because of this, some programmers prefer `lapply` (which *always* returns a `list`) or `vapply` (for which you must declare what kind of return value you expect ... and it fails when something else pops up). One might do:

```r
set.seed(2)
out <- vapply(seq_len(nrow(iris))[-1], function(i) {
  thisdat <- sample(iris$Sepal.Length, size = i)
  t.test(thisdat, mu = 5)$p.value
}, numeric(1))
```

(Try changing `numeric(1)` to `numeric(2)` and you'll see the error of `values must be length 2, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1`.)

For the `lapply` option, it is very similar to my fourth method, below.

Note that `length(out)` here will be `nrow(iris)-1`, because we skip it on the input vector of `seq_len(nrow(iris))[-1]`. This means that technically there will be a difference in `summary(out)`: there will not be the `NA`. All numbers are otherwise equal.

### 3. `for` loop, full model

Here, we need to store a lot more than just a single number, so we need to store it in the `list`.

```r
set.seed(2)
out <- vector("list", nrow(iris))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(iris))[-1]) {
  thisdat <- sample(iris$Sepal.Length, size = i)
  out[[i]] <- t.test(thisdat, mu = 5)
}
str(out[1:3])
# List of 3
#  $ : NULL
#  $ :List of 9
#   ..$ statistic  : Named num 1.31
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
#   ..$ parameter  : Named num 1
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
#   ..$ p.value    : num 0.416
#   ..$ conf.int   : num [1:2] -2.41 14.11
#   .. ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
#   ..$ estimate   : Named num 5.85
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean of x"
#   ..$ null.value : Named num 5
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean"
#   ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
#   ..$ method     : chr "One Sample t-test"
#   ..$ data.name  : chr "thisdat"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
#  $ :List of 9
#   ..$ statistic  : Named num 1.76
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
#   ..$ parameter  : Named num 2
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
#   ..$ p.value    : num 0.22
#   ..$ conf.int   : num [1:2] 3.61 8.33
#   .. ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
#   ..$ estimate   : Named num 5.97
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean of x"
#   ..$ null.value : Named num 5
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean"
#   ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
#   ..$ method     : chr "One Sample t-test"
#   ..$ data.name  : chr "thisdat"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

The list is quite long, but you can see that (1) the first element is empty, not surprising since we skip `i` of 1; and (2) each of the elements after that contain everything you would expect a model to have.

Okay, let's walk through that. We first allocate the full list, and then run the `for` loop as we did before. The only difference in the loop is that we store the entire model (needing `out[[i]]` instead of `out[i]`) instead of just the `$p.value`. Now, to be able to get to the p-value, we can use a `for` loop or `sapply`, I'll demo the latter:

```r
head(sapply(out[-1], `[[`, "p.value"))
# [1] 0.41561507 0.22019340 0.05766889 0.08544124 0.03243253 0.09059092

# more verbose, same thing though, showing the "anonymous-function" definition
head(sapply(out[-1], function(m) m$p.value))
```

I used `out[-1]` because we know that the first one is empty. We could easily have done `out <- out[-1]` immediately after the `for` loop above.

One can grab any other property from the models, such as a model coefficient, by using the "anonymous-function" definition I demonstrated above.

### 4. `*sapply`, full model

This may not surprise you much.

```r
set.seed(2)
out <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(iris))[-1], function(i) {
  thisdat <- sample(iris$Sepal.Length, size = i)
  out[[i]] <- t.test(thisdat, mu = 5)
})
```

If you look at these, the first element is not empty (similar to the `sapply` example above) because we didn't even run or pre-allocate for it.

One can then do whatever you want on individual list elements:

```r
out[[1]]$p.value
# [1] 0.4156151

str(out[[17]])
# List of 9
#  $ statistic  : Named num 3.98
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
#  $ parameter  : Named num 17
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
#  $ p.value    : num 0.000974
#  $ conf.int   : num [1:2] 5.48 6.57
#   ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
#  $ estimate   : Named num 6.03
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean of x"
#  $ null.value : Named num 5
#   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean"
#  $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
#  $ method     : chr "One Sample t-test"
#  $ data.name  : chr "thisdat"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"

out[[19]]$statistic
#        t 
# 3.420489
```

If you wanted to retrieve all test-statistics, similar to getting the p-values, you could just do:

```r
head(sapply(out, `[[`, "statistic"))
#        t        t        t        t        t        t 
# 1.307692 1.761625 3.000000 2.273030 2.935307 2.014477
```

Answer (score 1):

@r2evans has a great answer. I'll just focus on your code and trying to get it to plot.

Improvements include:

1. `for` syntax is `for (i in seq_along(n))` to loop through each i. In your case, you actually want to do `for (i in 2:200)` because `i==1` will not be able to compute a p.value.
2. The sample of your data needs to be assigned to a variable. As is, nothing happens. Alternatively, you can directly put the `sample` statement in the `t.test()` call.
3. You want to save the result of each loop into pvalue. If it worked as is, `pvalue` would end up with the last value of your loop.

I like the `apply` series because you don't have to pre-allocate anything explicitly.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 50
results <- sapply(seq(2, n)
                  , function(n) {
                   t.test(sample(iris$Sepal.Length, n, replace = T), mu = 5.5, alternative = 'greater')$p.value
                  })

plot(y = results, x = seq(2, n))
```

In theory, all you would need to do is replace `iris$Sepal.Length` with `data$column1` and use whatever `n` you prefer.